# Python Pandas: delete rows in the past if there is a row on the 1st of january 2023 (grouped by user)

Tags: python, pandas

I try to force all users to have a date that starts at the earliest on the 1st of january 2023 with 3 use cases:

1. if there is already data on the 01/01/2023, I want to keep it and delete previous rows
2. If there is no data on the 01/01/2023 but older rows, I want to update the date to 01/01/2023
3. if the 1st row of a user if after the 01/01/2023, keep it.

I guess I should start with a groupby() but then i'm not sure what to do?

**Source data:**:

| USER | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | 01/06/2022 | 1000 |
| USER1 | 01/01/2023 | 1000 |
| USER1 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 |
| USER1 | 02/02/2023 | 1300 |
| USER2 | 01/06/**2021** | 1000 |
| USER2 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 |
| USER2 | 02/02/2023 | 1250 |
| USER3 | 02/06/2023 | 1250 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"USER" : ['USER1', 'USER1', 'USER1', 'USER1', 'USER2', 'USER2', 'USER2', 'USER3'],
        "Date" :['01/06/2022', '01/01/2023', '01/02/2023', '02/02/2023', '01/06/2021', '01/02/2023', '02/02/2023', '02/06/2023'],
        "Value" :['1000', '1000', '1200', '1300', '1000', '1200', '1250', '1250'],}
    )
```

**Target data:**:

| USER | Date | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | 01/01/2023 | 1000 | row before is deleted because there is a already a row on january 1st 2023 |
| USER1 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 |  |
| USER1 | 02/02/2023 | 1300 |  |
| USER2 | **01/01/2023** | 1000 | previous value "01/06/**2021**" is forced to 1st of january 2023 |
| USER2 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 |  |
| USER2 | 02/02/2023 | 1250 |  |
| USER3 | 02/06/2023 | 1250 | keep the value as is, it's already after the 1st of january 2023 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could force a minimal date with [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html), then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) keeping the latest row:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

out = (df.assign(Date=df['Date'].clip(lower=pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01')))
         .drop_duplicates(subset=['USER', 'Date'], keep='last')
       )
```

*NB. I am assuming that the dates are already sorted (per USER).*

Output:

```
    USER       Date Value
1  USER1 2023-01-01  1000
2  USER1 2023-01-02  1200
3  USER1 2023-02-02  1300
4  USER2 2023-01-01  1000
5  USER2 2023-01-02  1200
6  USER2 2023-02-02  1250
7  USER3 2023-02-06  1250
```

Intermediates:

```
    USER       Date Value       clip  duplicated
0  USER1 2022-01-06  1000 2023-01-01        True
1  USER1 2023-01-01  1000 2023-01-01       False
2  USER1 2023-01-02  1200 2023-01-02       False
3  USER1 2023-02-02  1300 2023-02-02       False
4  USER2 2021-01-06  1000 2023-01-01       False
5  USER2 2023-01-02  1200 2023-01-02       False
6  USER2 2023-02-02  1250 2023-02-02       False
7  USER3 2023-02-06  1250 2023-02-06       False
```

Comment: so quick! I didn't have time to correct my post that you already answered :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

date = pd.to_datetime('01/01/2023')

#test if greater or equal next values
m1 = df['Date'].ge(date).groupby(df['USER']).cummax()
#test if at least one match
m2 = df['USER'].isin(df.loc[df['Date'].eq(date),'USER'])

#set date
df.loc[~m1 & ~m2, 'Date'] = date

#remove previous less values if exist date
out = df[m1 | ~m2]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the cummax() does in the m1 condition

Comment: @Nico - It create Trues after first greater or equal `date` to end of group. Btw, if in input data are added `USER2  01/06/2020  2000`  row, in output need only one `USER2  01/01/2023  1000` or both `USER2  01/01/2023  1000` and `USER2  01/01/2023  2000` ?

Comment: it needs to keep only one line per date, so only `|USER2 | 01/01/2023 | 2000|`

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is the simplest and most broken down approach to your problem**

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')


filtered_df = (df[df['Date'] >= '2023-01-01']
               .sort_values('Date')
               .groupby('USER', as_index=False)
               .first())

filtered_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01')

result_df = pd.concat([filtered_df, df[df['Date'] >= '2023-01-01']])


result_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['USER', 'Date'], keep='first', inplace=True)


result_df.sort_values(['USER', 'Date'], inplace=True)
```

**Now you can print the result**

```
print(result_df)
```